# Reading from a text file in Java

Tags: java, text, io

I have a text file like this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

I need to be able to read each "Item X" into a string and ideally store all the strings as a vector / ArrayList.

I tried:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
is.read(); //looped for every line of text
```

but that seems to only handle integers.

Thanks

Comment: _but that seems to only handle integers._ It is its normal behaviour. From JavaDocs: _read(): Reads **the next byte of data** from the input stream._

Comment: What he said is right you have to decode the bytes back to chars. Check out this... http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/character_stream_reader.shtml

Comment: -1 for not doing **any** research on Javas' IO APIs...

Comment: +1 for putting a reason why you -1ed :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several answers here, the easiest would be to us a Scanner (in java.util).

It has several convenience methods like nextLine() and next() and nextInt(), so you could simply do the following:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  text.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Alternatively you could use a BufferedReader (in java.io):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
  text.add(line);
}
```

However Scanners are generally easier to work with.

Answer (score 4):

You should use FileUtils to do this.  It has a method named [readLines](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

```
public static List<String> readLines(File file, Charset encoding) throws IOException
```

> Reads the contents of a file line by line to a List of Strings. The file is always closed.

---

See @BackSlash's comment above to see how you're using `InputStream.read()` wrong.

---

@BackSlash also mentioned you can use [java.nio.file.Files#readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) but only if you're using Java 1.7 or later.

Comment: Although I agree with this method, I don't think it answers his question. I think his problem is more about encoding and reading the Byte Stream

Comment: @Jackie I think it *does* answer his question.  His question is about how to read a text file into a a List.  He's having a problem with his method, because he's using `read()` incorrectly, but if he knew about this library in the first place, he wouldn't care why `read()` doesn't work the way he wants.

Comment: There's no need to use `FileUtils`, also the `Files` class has a `readAllLines` method, so there is no need to import the apache commons package to do this

Comment: @BackSlash That's a good point.  The only caveat to that is you have to be using Java 7 to use `Files`.

Comment: @tieTYT I know, mine was just a "plus" to your answer, in fact it is easier to have something that works on every java version, and not only on the last one

Answer (score 2):

You could use Java 7's `Files#readAllLines`. A short one-liner and no 3rd party library imports necessary :)

```
List<String> lines = 
       Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        String [] tmp ;
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            tmp = line.Split(" ");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("file.txt"));
scan.nextLine();
```